# Where can I find the D&D 3.0 FAQ?

Tags: dnd-3e

I've seen reference in a few old posts about the D&D 3.0 FAQ that may shed some light on a subject my friends and I have been talking about, but I can't seem to find it available anywhere online. How can I find it?

Comment: If the subject you’ve been talking about can be phrased as an on topic question for the site it may make more sense to just ask it.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered but it doesn't provide enough clarification for my purposes.

Comment: @MrTumnus: If the question clearly matches your concern but the answers don't sufficiently address it, you should raise a bounty on the question. Otherwise, if your question is about a specific edge-case that's not addressed by a question about the broader issue, you may want to ask a question about that specific edge-case.

Comment: @V2Blast If I asked a question right now with almost the exact same wording as another but saying I want deeper proof it would either get downvoted into oblivion or marked as a duplicate. I knew what I was looking for and got the answer, why is this such an issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original site is long lost as WotC deleted old posts in or around 2020, but it was archived.

Here is the link to the [latest capture](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111194213/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a)